How can I exclude things from .bash_history?
Every time I run a program using the VSCode debugger, a line such as
 /usr/bin/env /bin/sh /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-agft2qoj.y5y

or
 /usr/bin/env /bin/sh /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-1ai4zqj4.nob

gets added to my .bash_history file.  How can I exclude these lines?

Also related: How to remove a single line from history?,  Methods for avoiding bash history logging?, How do I close a terminal without saving the history? and Temporarily suspend bash_history on a given shell?

In bash you would set
HISTIGNORE="*commandhere*"

For example, the following will exclude fortune from the history, but will store fortune -l:
HISTIGNORE="*secret.server.com*:ytalk*:fortune"

source
